# In console it works but in content script not

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, undefined

This is my first post because i have problem with my Chrome extension.
I need to add some buttons and stuff to page using content script. But my code:

```
function ModifyInsta() {
  var root = {
    img: document.getElementsByClassName("FFVAD"),
    btn: document.getElementsByClassName("ltpMr Slqrh")
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < root.btn.length; i++) {
    if (typeof root.btn[i].getElementsByClassName("btnInsta")[i] === 'undefined') {
      chrome.storage.sync.get("OPTION", function(data) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        var space = document.createElement("a");
        var txt1 = document.createTextNode("Download");
        var txt2 = document.createTextNode("");

        space.appendChild(txt2);
        root.btn[i].appendChild(space);

        img.appendChild(txt1);
        root.btn[i].appendChild(img);

        space.innerHTML = "&emsp;&ensp;";
        space.setAttribute('style', "cursor: default; user-select: none")

        if (data.OPTION == "download")
          img.setAttribute('src', chrome.extension.getURL('download.png'));
        else
          img.setAttribute('src', chrome.extension.getURL('view.png'));
        img.setAttribute('href', "#");
        img.setAttribute('role', "button");
        img.setAttribute('class', "btnInsta");
        img.setAttribute('style', "cursor: pointer; user-select: none");
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Works well in console on certain page but not in content script. It says `undefined` at `root.btn[i].appendChild(space);` ("Error in response to storage.get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined")... I dont really know whats wrong. Every time when I needed help I google for it.. but this problem I think is not possible to google.

Please help me. I tried everything

EDIT:

Piece of HTML:

`<section class="ltpMr Slqrh"><a class="fr66n tiVCN" href="#" role="button"><span class="Szr5J coreSpriteHeartOpen ">Páči sa mi to</span></a><a class="_15y0l OV9Wd" href="#" role="button"><span class="Szr5J coreSpriteComment">Komentovať</span></a><a class="wmtNn fscHb " href="#" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="Szr5J coreSpriteSaveOpen   ">Uložiť</span></a></section>`

Comment: Since you are having the root.btn[i] as an iterator object, it should be valid. What does "space" evaluate to?

Comment: Can you show html, on which you are trying to do this?

Comment: Not sure of what your problem is here, but do remember `getElementsByClassName` returns a live DOM list, it's not an array.  IOW: it can change under your nose.  To prevent this, you could do -> `btn: Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("ltpMr Slqrh"))`

Comment: @NitinSingh just space between default button and button added by me.

Comment: @Leo Odishvili OK

Comment: @Keith Not working :/

Comment: It means the page adds that element after your content script runs. Many modern pages render themselves dynamically after DOMContentLoaded event. You'll need to wait for the element to be added by periodically checking in setInterval or using MutationObserver. FWIW there may be several existing answers for this topic here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have already done this.. I have 3 seconds delay after loading page so function has 3 seconds dealy.. 
`setTimeout(function(){
    ModifyInsta();
   }, 3000);`

Comment: Ah, just noticed -> `chrome.storage.sync.get(`  that looks like an `async` op to me, seen as it's using a callback.  A simple solution here, change your `var i`, to `let i` to keep your `i` variable in scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
function ModifyInsta() {
var root = {
    img: document.getElementsByClassName("FFVAD"),
    btn: document.getElementsByClassName("ltpMr Slqrh")
};
for(let i = 0; i < root.btn.length; i++) {
    if (typeof root.btn[i].getElementsByClassName("btnInsta")[i] === 'undefined') {
        chrome.storage.sync.get("OPTION", function(data){
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            var space = document.createElement("a");
            var txt1 = document.createTextNode("Download");
            var txt2 = document.createTextNode("");

            space.appendChild(txt2);
            root.btn[i].appendChild(space);

            img.appendChild(txt1);
            root.btn[i].appendChild(img);

            space.innerHTML = "&emsp;&ensp;";
            space.setAttribute('style', "cursor: default; user-select: none")

            if (data.OPTION == "download")
                img.setAttribute('src', chrome.extension.getURL('download.png'));
            else
                img.setAttribute('src', chrome.extension.getURL('view.png'));
            img.setAttribute('href', "#");
            img.setAttribute('role', "button");
            img.setAttribute('class', "btnInsta");
            img.setAttribute('style', "cursor: pointer; user-select: none");
        });
    }
}
```

}

@Keith Thanks so much

Comment: No problem,.. if your coding for Chrome, you should be free to just avoid `var` altogether and stick to `const / let`,